# Proof real number $\sqrt{3}$ is an irrational number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Given: Let $n$ be an integer. Then $n^2=3a$ for some integer $a$ if and only if $n=3b$ for some integer $b$.

**Proof** real number $\sqrt{3}$ is an irrational number.

Here is I have so far:
Assume $\sqrt{3}=a/b$ where $a,b$ are integers. 
Then $a^2=3(b^2)$,
which means $a^2=3c$, where $c$ is some integer.

next is what I'm confused about:
With the given fact I can get $a=3d$ where $d$ is integer in order to let $a^2=3c$

I'm not quite sure how to continue this.. Can someone please help?

Comment: Your a and b are just arbitrary integers whose quotient is sqrt(3), correct?  You can't assume that 3 divides a.  However, you can assume that a and b are such that they share no common factors, so that a^2 and b^2 share no common factors, and hence, that a^2 divides 3.  Since 3 is prime, a^2 is thus equal to 1 or 3, which implies that a is an integer that divides 1 or divides 3.  See what you can get with this head-start.

Comment: I don't know how to connect the given fact to the proof..

Comment: Does the given fact mean:only when n is divided by 3, n^2 is divided by 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $3m^2=n^2$. Then the multiplicity of the factor $3$ in the prime decomposition of the LHS is odd, while it is even for the RHS, a contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure.. 3*4=12 is still a even number?

Comment: I didn't say that the LHS is odd, did I ?

Comment: Sorry..I just don't get it. Is there any way I can make the given fact useful?

Comment: Yes, understand why the multiplicities need to be odd on the left and even on the right.